# WireShark TSL Handshake issue

Tags: ssl, wireshark

From the log, I can see following "Client hello, Server Hello,Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message" back and forth. But, I am not able to see the "Certificate, Server key exchange, Server Hello Done" package.

I can verify in IIS 10 that port 443 is bind to a certificate and SSL is set to required. I am using Windows Server 2022 where we use TSL 1.2 and I know TSL 1.3 is enabled in Windows Server 2022.

Why I am not seeing the Certificate exchange and server hello done?

Comment: Are you using TLS 1.3 perchance? Note that this is not a programming question and hence off topic on [so].

Comment: It seems like even though in the registry I have tls 1.2 enabled, IIS 10 in windows server 2022 is using tls 1.3

Comment: Which means that the certificates are encrypted as well, any package after the hello should be. Furthermore, it may be using the session resumption mechanism.

Comment: Well my issue is that my site shows "the site can't be reached" and I am trying to figure out why that is happening, it works on other OS just not Windows Server 2022. In chrome, the connection isn't secure and I'm not sure why, IIS shows that the certificate is correct and valid.